# Why do I get extra "nodes" when parsing XML in Scala?

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

Here is the XML that's returned by my web server

```
<root>
    <item attr="test1">
    <item attr="test2">
</root>
```

Here is the Scala Code

```
var url = "http://mywebserver/my.xml"
val xml = XML.load(url)
logger.info(s"The XML is: $xml")
var items = xml.child
logger.info(s"items: $items")
items.foreach(item => {
  logger.info(item.toString())
  val attr = item.attribute("attr")
  logger.info(s"Attribute: $attr")
})
```

The XML logged is the copy of the XML returned by the web server
However the foreach loop prints

```
INFO myclassName - 
INFO myclassName - Attribute: None
INFO myclassName - <item attr="test1">
INFO myclassName - Attribute: test1
INFO myclassName - 
INFO myclassName - Attribute: None
INFO myclassName - <item attr="test2">
INFO myclassName - Attribute: test2
```

Where are the extra blank nodes coming from? Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<foo><bar></bar></foo>` and `<foo> <bar> </bar> </foo>` are different XML. In the XML spec, the characters between tags--including whitespace--form a "text element" child of the enclosing tag, and Scala's XML parsing is simply honoring the spec by reading your whitespace as text elements.